# Moving from mysql_connect to PDO on my site

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I have a script that searches without refreshing the page. I'm trying to move from old `mysql_connect` to new `PDO` connection to make it more secure. I need help changing my PDO script so that it works with the post function.

My HTML script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".search").click(function(){
            $.post("search.php", { keywords: $(".keywords").val() }, function(data){
                $("div#content").empty()
                $.each(data, function(){
                    $("div#content").append("- <a href='#?id=" + this.id + "'>" + this.title + "</a><br>");
                });
            }, "json");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="search" class="keywords">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="search">
<div id="content">
</div>
```

And this is my working search script:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("pirateconnection", $link);

$keywords = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["keywords"] );

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE title LIKE '%". $keywords ."%'");

$arr = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $query ) )
{
    $arr[] = array( "id" => $row["id"], "title" => $row["title"]);
}

echo json_encode( $arr );
?>
```

I made a new script with PDO connection:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pirateconnection','root','');

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `media`.`title` FROM `media` WHERE `media`.`title` LIKE :keywords");

$keywords = (isset($_POST['keywords']) === true) ? $_POST['keywords'] : '';
$query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $keywords . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

try {
    $query->execute();

    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<pre>', print_r($rows, true), '</pre>';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Now I need to get the PDO script working with the html/jquery post script.

Comment: What doesnt work, exactly?

Comment: So what is the problem? I don't get it. Look, you're the one there, you see the output, the differences, the arrays. Please try to explain what is the actual problem you cannot solve.

Comment: Everything works perfectly, i'm just trying to move from mysql_connect to PDO connection, change scripts. first search.php file works. I'm trying to swap that one to the pdo connection one.

Comment: Post does not show anything. That is my problem

Comment: @sw0o0sh That is already a lot more than you previously shared with us :). Please show some debugging effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, what you need is to replace the `try...catch` segment with the following for the same jQuery to work

```
$arr = array();
$query->execute();
while( $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $arr[] = array( "id" => $row["id"], "title" => $row["title"]);
}
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

Also, change your preparation query to include the `id` too:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `media`.`id`, `media`.`title` FROM `media` WHERE `media`.`title` LIKE :keywords");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query->execute();
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {
     $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
exit;
}
```